# Use different domains in page tree

Tags: typo3

I have e.g. this page tree:

```
- root
   -- subpage 1
   --- subpage1.1
   -- subpage 2
   --- subpage 2.1
   --- subpage 2.2
   -- subpage 3
   …
```

Now I have to link an additional domain to subpage 2, so all links under subpage 2 have to use this domain. All Links to other parts must use the root-domain. Also the menu must use the respective domains.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TYPO3 =< 8.7 LTS

**To enable typolinks** across domains you must activate it with TypoScript Setup:

```
config.typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains = 1
```

Setting the above one, also sets (TypoScript Setup)

```
config.typolinkCheckRootline = 1
```

I've tested it and it works so far for me.

---

### TYPO3 >= 9.0

*Note about TYPO3 >= 9.0*

Since TYPO3 9.0 `config.typolinkCheckRootline` is always active. You must safely remove it therefore.

*Note about TYPO3 >= 9.4*

If you use the new site configuration introduced in 9.4, you don't need `config.typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains` anymore.

Comment: what about the rest of the configuration ? how do you get the addtional domain to end up on subpage 2?

Comment: @webMan Just by adding a sys_domain record on "subpage 2". that should be enough.